# $resource usage in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am fairly new to AngularJS and trying to get data via $resource in my service.

```
vetoApp.service('adminKeyService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
this.IsAdmin = function(key) {
    var vetoAPI = $resource("http://localhost/mcspro/veto/api/getadminkey/", { callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'}, { get: { method:'GET' } } );
    return vetoAPI.get({ k: key});
}
}]);
```

My api call returns this simple JSON data:

```
{
  "isAdmin": false
}
```

depending to the value of key. Now, in controller when I call this service, I get something like

```
d {$promise: d, $resolved: false} $promise: d $resolved: true isAdmin: false __proto__: d
```

My controller has following code to call the service and log it in console:

```
var isAdmin = adminKeyService.IsAdmin($scope.adminkey);
console.log(isAdmin);
```

How would I get `isAdmin` value from this object?

Comment: How do you use this `isAdmin` variable? $resourse returns a promise, not just plain value.

Comment: that was the problem that i was getting the promise and how to get value from promise. The post you mentioned solved the issue, thanks.